# Table being deleted after traversal

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, hashtable

For some reason, whenever I access any data in my table, the contents get replaced with `null`. The table is an array of linked lists.

```
void print(struct foo ** bar) {
    struct foo ** helper = bar;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d: ", i);
        while (helper[i] != NULL) {
            printf("%s ", helper[i]->data);
            helper[i] = helper[i]->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Nothing I try works. The table prints once, then returns `null` the second time around.

Comment: `helper[i] = helper[i]->next;` destructs / modifies the table while printing.

Comment: @wildplasser What should I use instead?

Comment: A temporary variable, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you modify your array with

```
helper[i] = helper[i]->next;
```

setting it eventually to NULL.
So, your problem is no surprise.

If you want to loop through your hash table, try

```
struct foo *helper;
for (i = 0; i < tablesize; i++) {
    printf("%d: ", i);
    for (helper = bar[i]; helper != NULL; helper = helper->next)
        printf("%s ", helper->data);

    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void print(struct foo ** bar) {

    int i;
    struct foo *ptr ;

    for (i = 0; i < tablesize; i++) {
        if (!bar[i]) continue;
        printf("%d: ", i);

        for (ptr=bar[i] ; ptr ; ptr = ptr->next ) {
            printf("%s ", ptr->data);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```